# Scapy packet time interpretation

Tags: python-2.7, packet, scapy

I was wondering what is the difference between using pkt.time and pkt[IP].time since they both give different times for the same packet.

I was also wondering how to interpret packet time such as 1430123453.564733

If anyone has an idea or knows where I can find such information it would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**pkt.time** gives you the epoch time that is included in the FRAME layer of the packet in wireshark.

Just after the notation **pkt[IP].time** gives you the time that is included in the IP layer of the packet in wireshark. But the IP layer has no time, so I don't think this command will work.